# Bot sends a embed when joins a server

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im trying to make my bot send a embed in the server that it joins (E.G a thank you for inviting and what the bot can do).This is the error that I am getting.

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' &&  client.user.me.permissions.has("send_messages"))
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
```

this is the code that i am using in the index.js file

````
client.on('guildCreate', message => {

    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' &&  client.user.me.permissions.has("send_messages"))

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle('Thank You')
    .setDescription("Thank you for inviting Rynwin to your server. To get the command list please do /help.\n \n The default Bot prefix is ```<```")        
    .addFields([
        {
            name: "Our Support Server",
            value: "If you require assistance or would like to get daily bot updates please join our support discord [here] ()"
        },
        
        {
        name: "Commands",
        value: "Try some of these commands; \n\n**/prefix <prefix>** - Sets the server prefix\n\n**/help** -  Get the command list or information on a command \n\n**/botinfo** - Shows info on the bot"
        },



    channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })

    ])
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong on the first 2 lines. Firstly, `guildCreate` gives a `Guild` instance, not a message. Secondly, you aren't checking the correct channel type or permission. Here is the fixed code:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {

    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT' &&  guild.me.permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
// GUILD_TEXT channel type, guild.me for client guild member, and uppercase permission
// rest of code...
}
```

Comment: i now get this: 
   `` channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }) ``
                            ^

``ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization``

Comment: You have to declare `embed` before using it

Comment: i think i have declared an embed?,I have used what i normally use for an embed